# Defining a `... = ` type method with parameters

Tags: ruby

It is possible to define a method in `... =` format like this:

```
class A
  def f= x
    puts x
  end
end

A.new.f = 5
```

But is it possible to define a method in this format with arguments so that it can be used like the following?

```
A.new.f(a, b, c) = 5
```

**Edit**

You can do this with `[]=`

```
class A
  def []= x, y, z
    puts x, y, z
  end
end

A.new[1, 2] = 3
```

Is this an exceptional case?

Comment: someting= methods in Ruby are pretty exceptional, avoid using them unless you have to. That said, they come very handy for DSLized APIs. For example, they also always return their argument as a return value.

Comment: I thought every setter in Ruby was defined this way (i.e. `def setter= ...`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A.new.f(a, b, c) = 5
```

is syntax error, so for sure not (this doesn't make sense too ;)

`[]` is just sugar for .send(:[]=, ...) which is just setter with fancy name.

You can define setter with multiple arguments, but the only way to use it is by

`A.new.send(:f=, "first", "second")`

because parser doesn't allow syntax like A.new.foo = "first", "second".

Answer (score 0):

The ruby `...` and `..` are string literals to construct `Range` objects. You can make your object useable by `Range` objects.

See the first chapter of http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html

EDITED

foo.rb

```
class A
  def ...(a)
    p a
  end
end
```

$ ruby foo.rb

```
foo.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tDOT3
  def ...(a)
         ^
foo.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

BUT! You can use define_method to define a method called `...` but you will only be able to call it via `send` so it's quite useless.

```
$ irb
1.9.3p194 :001 > class A; end
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :002 > A.send(:define_method, :'...') { puts 'hello' }
 => #<Proc:0x007fe1931dbb50@(irb):2 (lambda)> 
1.9.3p194 :003 > A.new.send(:'...')
hello
 => nil
```

Comment: The anonymous person who downvoted a newbie's answer, please come forth and state what is wrong with the answer.

Comment: They downvoted your answer because it did not answer the question. The question is about the something=() methods, while you misunderstoot the question as referring to the ellipsis literal "...". The asker did not ask clearly, he meant methods like "someobject.name = 'Peter'", which can be defined as "def name=()".

Comment: Then I gave a pretty good answer to a not asked question I guess ;) Thank's for letting me know.